# How to wake up the blue alpaca in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In my Re-Tail shop, there is a blue alpaca who appears to be Reese's fiance. When I try to wake him up, Reese says that he is tired from working all night on something. How do I wake him up and what is he for?

Comment: I didn't know..

Comment: That's fine, duplicates happen all the time. At least you got your answer.